# Inline Citations when Critiquing a Single Source (APA)

Tags: citations, apa

I am writing an essay which is entirely a response to a single source.  I mention the source in my introduction paragraph, and I give a full reference at the end.

Is it also required that I include inline citations for every direct quote or idea that I use, when the reader knows it is all coming from one place?

I will be stating "The author says, "...." so it should be clear that the thoughts are not my own.

Answer (score 1):

When citing the same source multiple times in a paragraph (and from there an extension being to the entire paper, as is the case in your question), you can do the following (borrowed from [here](http://owll.massey.ac.nz/referencing/apa-in-text-citation.php#multiple-citations)):

> Introduce the source early in the paragraph, with the author as part of the sentence rather than in brackets:
>
> Example: Lazar (2006) describes several aspects of the data gathering process.
>
> For the rest of the paragraph, you can refer back to the author by name or pronoun when elaborating on their ideas:
>
> Example: He notes that the relevance and number of questions can affect participation rates. Lazar also found that…
>
> As long as it is clear to the reader that all of the ideas come from that same source, there is no risk of plagiarism and the paragraph flows well.
>
> Note that if you put the author's name in brackets later on in the paragraph (for example, if you include a quotation from that source) you should always include the year of publication in the brackets.

Main reference:

- http://owll.massey.ac.nz/referencing/apa-in-text-citation.php#multiple-citations

Other references:

- http://libguides.css.edu/content.php?pid=61826&sid=454619
- http://nova.campusguides.com/apa-citing-in-body-of-paper

Answer (score 0):

I would reference page, paragraph, or section numbers, in my inline/footnote citations and omit everything else.